# In Symfony where should I put entity dependant functions

Tags: class, symfony

I have this code in my controller, it takes 'procedure_type' from the request and checks to see if a ProcedureType with that name exists. If it does it uses the object, if not it creates a new ProcedureType, then return the new object to use.

```
// Check the typed in ProcedureType against existing types.
$procedureTypes = $entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:ProcedureType')->findBy(array('name' => $request->request->get('procedure_type'), 'vendor' => $vendorId));
if (empty($procedureTypes)) {
    // Create Procedure Type
    $procedureType = new ProcedureType();
    $procedureType->setVendor($vendor)
                  ->setName($request->request->get('procedure_type'))
                  ->setCreated(new \DateTime())
                  ->setUpdated($procedureType->getCreated());
    $entityManager->persist($procedureType);
} else {
    $procedureType = $procedureTypes[0];
}
```

I don't think this is the best way to do this, I'd like to move the code into a function, say checkProcedureType(), but I don't know where the best place is to put that. I don't think it could go in the Entity or Repository classes, and moving it to a private function in the controller doesn't feel right.

I'm sure there is a class type that I'm not aware of, that extends the Entity. Or maybe I should just put these functions in my entity classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Service are the answer to almost everything in Symfony 2. Create a service like this :

```
namespace Your\Bundle\Service;

class ProcedureService // Call this the way you want
{
    protected $entityManager;

    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function callMeTheWayYouWant($vendorId, $vendor)
    {
        // Check the typed in ProcedureType against existing types.
        $procedureTypes = $this->entityManager->getRepository('IncompassSurgeryBundle:ProcedureType')->findBy(array('name' => $request->request->get('procedure_type'), 'vendor' => $vendorId));
        if (empty($procedureTypes)) {
            // Create Procedure Type
            $procedureType = new ProcedureType();
            $procedureType->setVendor($vendor)
                ->setName($request->request->get('procedure_type'))
                ->setCreated(new \DateTime())
                ->setUpdated($procedureType->getCreated());
            $this->entityManager->persist($procedureType);
        } else {
            $procedureType = $procedureTypes[0];
        }

        // The rest of your code
    }
}
```

In your services.yml file :

```
  your_service:
    class: Your\Bundle\Service\ProcedureService
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
```

Then use it in your controller :

```
$this->get('your_service')->callMeTheWayYouWant($vendorId, $vendor);
```

Answer (score 1):

If logic is somehow related to acessing database I always go for repository. However, if cases like yours, I tend to analyze it's dependency map.

> Does your code repeats in some other method within same class, only?

If so, go for `private` method.

> Is this part of code reused somewhere else but **does not rely** on some services?

You could externalize logic by creating separate class and `static` method which executes the code. **Beware: Tends to get messy really quick**

> Finally, does your code rely on services/configuration?

Create a separate service, inject the services/configuration and invoke it's method. Adds a bit of overhead, if your abuse it, but you should be fine

Personally, in your example, I would go for `private` method, but that's just my opinion.